# Conversion of word document into excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written a code to convert a Word document into an excel sheet.
The problem is that whenever there is a point starting with bullets in Word document line after a colon, after getting converted into excel sheet it is appearing into different cells or say column.
I want everything into the same cell but it is creating extra cells.
I want a code to handle this problem.
suppose if the line is:
I have three cars:
all belong to the same brand
.car1
.car2
.car3
 in excel sheet the data is comming like
i have three cars,all belongs to same brand,car1,car2,car3
take commas as cells, but I want each data to be in the same cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have converted a word document having tables into excel sheet using java apache poi. some of the table values contains paragraphs with colon and bullets so when i am converting it into excel the part in word document which is after bullets or colon gets splitted to another cell.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? can you edit your question and add some code ( when you parse word document and write into excel file ) ?

Comment: i have used apache poi to convert word in to excel. using workbook.

Comment: if (name!=null) {
     
     Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
     
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name,"\t");
     int cellnum = 0;
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
      String token = st.nextToken();
      cell.setCellValue(token);
      
     }

Comment: i have written this code for taking value from word document and creating a cell in excel sheet for each token.....but what is happening is whenever it is getting newline in word document it is considering it as separate token and that why it is splitting a paragraph with line break in to different cells.